# REST GET request doesn't show List<object> as JSON

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, java-8, get

I am new to Spingboot, doing a demo (an example) of a very simple application to display a list of classes as a JSON, but I get an error. What did I miss in my configuration/dependencies?

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <parent>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
          <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
     </parent>
     <groupId>com.beniregev</groupId>
     <artifactId>booking-demo</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <name>booking-demo</name>
     <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

     <properties>
          <java.version>1.8</java.version>
     </properties>

     <dependencies>
          <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>
     </dependencies>

     <build>
          <plugins>
                <plugin>
                     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
          </plugins>
     </build>

 </project>
```

My directories structure:
[image: Application Directories structure]

DemoController.java - this is working ("localhost:8080/hello")

```
package com.beniregev.bookingdemo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

HotelBooking.java

```
package com.beniregev.bookingdemo;

public class HotelBooking {
    private String hotelName;
    private double pricePerNight;
    private int numberOfNights;

    public HotelBooking(String hotelName, double pricePerNight, int numberOfNights) {
        this.hotelName = hotelName;
        this.pricePerNight = pricePerNight;
        this.numberOfNights = numberOfNights;
    }

    public String getHotelName() {
        return hotelName;
    }

    public double getPricePerNight() {
        return pricePerNight;
    }

    public int getNumberOfNights() {
        return numberOfNights;
    }

    public double getTotalPrica() {
        return pricePerNight * numberOfNights;
    }
}
```

BookingController.java

```
package com.beniregev.bookingdemo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/bookings")
public class BookingController {
    private List<HotelBooking> bookings;

    public BookingController() {
        bookings = new ArrayList<>();

        bookings.add(new HotelBooking("Marriot", 200.50, 3));
        bookings.add(new HotelBooking("Novotel", 140.74, 1));
        bookings.add(new HotelBooking("Ibis", 90.0, 4));
        bookings.add(new HotelBooking("Hilton", 150.60, 5));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<HotelBooking> getAll() {
        return bookings;
    }
}
```

BookingDemoApplication.java

```
package com.beniregev.bookingdemo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BookingDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BookingDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I am using IntelliJ 2018.3, JDK 1.8.0_144 and Springboot.
When I am running the server and go to "localhost:8080/bookings/all" instead of a JSON I get the following:
[image: JSON is not displayed]

Why the List is not displayed as JSON? What am I missing?

I am expecting to receive something like the following:
[image: Expected result- JSON]

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: What template engine do you use? Your controller returns `JSON` payload properly. But on client side you expect some kind of an `HTML` which already has this payload stored under `JSONObject` variable. It does not work this way. You need to in `JQuery` do a request and on success show `JSON` as part of the page. Or, you need to return in controller `ModelAndView` class which will print given list as JSON object. But in this case you need template engine properly configured.

Comment: I have no JavaScript, JQuery, CSS or any front-end on this project. I don't know JQuery, can you advise? For my controller I use `@RestController` (that allow to return anything and not `@Controller` (that require to return `ModelAndView`) - at least for my understanding.

Comment: But how you would get `HTML` page then? What is the `URL` you are trying to call? `"localhost:8080/bookings/all`? What is the string after `#`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BookingController#getAll()` method returns `List` which will be converted to `JSON` payload. ON client side you will see it as a `JSON`. It will not appear magically as `JSONObject` variable in `HTML` page. To do that you need [template engine](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-template-engines). You can also use static `index.html` file to play with your `API` on client side. It is much simpler to start from.

To do that, you need to add to `resources/static` folder `index.html` file with content like below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hotel bookings</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hotel bookings</h1>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Number of nights</th>
        <th scope="col">Price per night</th>
        <th scope="col">Total price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="bookingsBody"></tbody>
</table>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function laodAllHotelBookings() {
        var url = '/bookings/all/';
        var headers = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
        axios.get(url, headers).then(res => {
            let bookingsBody = $('.bookingsBody');
            let data = res.data;
            $.each(Object.keys(data), function (index, key) {
                let item = data[key];
                var row = $('<tr>');
                row.append($('<th>').text(index));
                row.append($('<td>').text(item.hotelName));
                row.append($('<td>').text(item.pricePerNight));
                row.append($('<td>').text(item.numberOfNights));
                row.append($('<td>').text(item.totalPrice));

                bookingsBody.append(row);
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("error", error);
            const errorMsg = 'There was an error fetching the menu';
            console.log(errorMsg);
        });
    }

    laodAllHotelBookings();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

To `application.properties` file add below line:

```
spring.resources.static-locations[0]=file:src/main/resources/static/
```

It should be enough to see under `http://localhost:8080/` below content:
[image]

When you are working with `prices` and generally `money` in `Java` always use `BigDecimal`. I have fixed your `POJO`:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class HotelBooking {
    private String hotelName;
    private BigDecimal pricePerNight;
    private int numberOfNights;

    public HotelBooking(String hotelName, BigDecimal pricePerNight, int numberOfNights) {
        this.hotelName = hotelName;
        this.pricePerNight = pricePerNight;
        this.numberOfNights = numberOfNights;
    }

    public String getHotelName() {
        return hotelName;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPricePerNight() {
        return pricePerNight;
    }

    public int getNumberOfNights() {
        return numberOfNights;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTotalPrice() {
        return pricePerNight.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(numberOfNights));
    }
}
```

Your controller constructor could look like below:

```
public BookingController() {
    bookings = new ArrayList<>();

    bookings.add(new HotelBooking("Marriot", new BigDecimal("200.50"), 3));
    bookings.add(new HotelBooking("Novotel", new BigDecimal("140.74"), 1));
    bookings.add(new HotelBooking("Ibis", new BigDecimal("90.0"), 4));
    bookings.add(new HotelBooking("Hilton", new BigDecimal("150.60"), 5));
}
```

In example `inex.html` I used [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) and [`bootstrap`](https://getbootstrap.com/) libraries.

Comment: I installed **JSONView** extension on Chome from ***Chrome Web Store*** and I see JSON and not plain text. No need for any HTML or JavaScript code.

Comment: @BinyaminRegev, of course it is not required. My example just shows how it could look like when it would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Class `HotelBooking` needs to be a JavaBean. In order for it to be one, it must:

1. Have an constructor with no parameters
2. Have getter AND setters for all properties

So, if you change your class to this:

```
package com.beniregev.bookingdemo;

public class HotelBooking {
    private String hotelName;
    private double pricePerNight;
    private int numberOfNights;

    public HoterBooking() 
    {
    }

    public HotelBooking(String hotelName, double pricePerNight, int numberOfNights) {
        this.hotelName = hotelName;
        this.pricePerNight = pricePerNight;
        this.numberOfNights = numberOfNights;
    }

    public String getHotelName() {
        return hotelName;
    }

    public void setHotelName(String val) {
        this.hotelName = val;
    }

    public double getPricePerNight() {
        return pricePerNight;
    }

    public void setPricePerNight(double val) {
        this.pricePerNight = val;
    }

    public int getNumberOfNights() {
        return numberOfNights;
    }

    public void setNumberOfNights(int val) {
        this.numberOfNights = val;
    }

    public double getTotalPrica() {
        return pricePerNight * numberOfNights;
    }
}
```

It should work as expected.

By the way. **DO NOT** use `double` type for money values. Use `java.math.BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: For serialisation we do not need `default constructor`. `Jackson` properly serialise this bean even without it.

Comment: It's just a demo/example for my personal use, not related to any project. But thank you for the tip about best practice.